# Can't cancel left click on mails

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following code to cancel the left click on a webpage :

```
window.onclick = function(event){
    return false;
}
```

The problem I have now is that it doesn't seem to work with some elements like mails.
Do you know why ?

Comment: You need to add further details to your question, otherwise it is far too vague.

Comment: If you use this code on the gmail webpage for example, it doesn't work with mails, the same for hotmail. Normally, when you click on a mail it would not open but it does.

Comment: This could have a bazillion reasons, but probably the event's propagation is stopped at some point, see: http://jsfiddle.net/kTgv9/

Comment: I tried to add "element.addEventListener('click', function(e){e.stopPropagation();})" and "var element = event.srcElement||event.target" in my onclick function but it doesn't fix the problem :(

Comment: I was just trying to demonstrate what might be happening and why the handler is never called. We don't know anything about your use case and chances are you won't be able to fix it at all.

Comment: Ok so I'm working on a firefox plugin. Thanks to "window.opener" I can access to the firefox window. Now I do "window.opener.onclick = function(e){return false;}" and nothing else. It works for many elements but not for google mails for example. Like you said, it's probably the event's propagation which is stopped at some point.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others your problem is that the event bubbling is probably stopped by `stopPropagation()`. You could overwrite the function with an empty one before the event is created to stop this behavior.

Note: I don't know if it works like this for plugins, and this could cause various issues on the websites you are visiting. Therefore I wouldn't advice implementing it like this, but if you really want you probably could.

In below snipped you can see how this could be done. By removing the first line `stopPropagation()` will function as normal.

```js
Event.prototype.stopPropagation = () => {};

window.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('Propagation not stopped'));
document.querySelector('#propstopper').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('Propagation stopped');
});
```

```html
<div id='prop'>
  <div id='propstopper'>
    Propgation stopper
  </div>
</div>
```